# Missing Scroll Bar

Tags: css, browser, html, scroll, scrollbar

I seem to be missing a horizontal scroll bar on this page, http://www.animefushigi.com/

If you make your browser window skinner, half the page will be cut off but there will be no scroll bar.

I believe the main content width should be 1024 px before the need of a scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

because the wrapper div does not have a stable min-width(and for browser which not support min-width, such as ie6, there is a child div .wrapper has a stable width in this case, so it will be ok,too ),which should be setted.

e.g.
//add css

```
#master_wrapper{min-width:1000px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `overflow:hidden` is used to clear floats in a couple of places. If you get rid of it on `#master_wrapper` then the horizontal scrollbar will return. However this will cause that element to collapse to a height of `0` and making this [image disappear](http://www.animefushigi.com/wp-content/themes/af-red/images/header_img.jpg) from your page. You can however rearrange your background images using the `html` for one of them to sort that issue out.

Comment: I added `* {overflow:auto !important}` at the bottom of the CSS and couldn't figure it out. Tried with `scroll` too. Have a solution?